# load data on change of dropdown in other component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have component A which is navbar and component B which is list view

`Navbar` has dropdown where all the users are listed, onInit method of `component B` all the data is loaded in the `Component B` Table that selected user is in local storage, now i want when the user changes the users from dropdown then that users data should automatically be refreshed in the `Component B` selected users are saved in localstorage. Is there anyway i can call method of second component from first component.

> Navbar Component

```
 <select class="form-control"(change)="selectUsers($event)" [(ngModel)]="UserId">
           <option *ngFor="let opt of userlist" value={{opt.UserId}}>{{opt?.userName}}
 </option>
 </select>



 selectUsers(event) {
     this.Service.SelectedUserId = event.target.value;
  }
```

> In Service File

```
 set SelectedUserId(value: string) {
    if (value) localStorage.setItem('ActiveUserId', value);
  }
```

> Component B:

```
 fetch() {
    this.Userslist = [];
    this.param.userId = localStorage.getItem('ActiveUserId');
    this.service.getUsers(this.param).subscribe((data => {
      this.Userslist = data.response;
   }
 }
```

> In View:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of Userslist | paginate:{itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:p} ; let i=index"
..
..
</tbody>
```

Any solution to resolve this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup a common service which is shared by the two components. Lets assume its called `testService`.

so service will be like.

```
export class testService {
    testEmitter: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>()
    testObserver$: Observable<void>;

    constructor () {
        this.testObserver$ = this.testEmitter.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Now the power of this pattern is that we can listen for `next` of the subject from any component in the application and perform action!

so in the navbar we start the `next` which will trigger action on all the observables!

```
 selectUsers(event) {
     this.Service.SelectedUserId = event.target.value;
    this.testService.next();
  }
```

So we subscribe on the component where the refresh should happen, and then reload the grid.

child component.

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription.add(
            this.testService.testObserver$.subscribe(() => {
                this.fetch();
            })
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

You can also emit objects like `{eventType: 'test', data: {}}` inside the `next` and then add multiple if conditions to validate the eventType and perform multiple actions on the same subject!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Can i navigate to the same route after i changes the local storage parameter and it will execute the `oninit` method of `component B` which `refetch` the data

Comment: @user3653474 If it works for you then do it, use this pattern to communicate between components of any depth!